# Isn't C# invocation of stored javaScript in MongoDB more efficient, and better than using MongoDB C# Driver Query API?

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, stored-procedures

All:

Here is the information about my development environment:

- MongoDB 3.0.0

  MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714

  Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

  .NET Framework 4.0

Using the MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714 API, I can construct queries using IMongoQuery and the Query object,

However, I find it difficult to implement queries using the  MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714 API when the query involves a lot of "quasi-joins" between MongoDB Collections.

Also, I believe it slows performance if you bring in large amount of data from MongoDB world into C# world as POCO objects in a list.

So, I was thinking if it would be good to adopt the implementation practice of using C# to invoke  stored JavaScript in MongoDB.

```
       var sysJs = DBConnection.database.GetCollection("system.js");

            sysJs.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", "getUsers"));

            var code =     File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Hos/quasiStoredProcedures    JS/getUsers.js"));


            var codeDocument = new BsonDocument("value", new        BsonJavaScript(code));

            codeDocument.Add(new BsonElement("_id", "getUsers"));

            sysJs.Insert(codeDocument);

 BsonValue getUsers = DBConnection.database.Eval("getUsers");


            BsonValue bv3 =      DBConnection.database.Eval(getUsers.AsBsonJavaScript.Code, null
                                                                                                ,
loggedInUser.CompanyID
                                                                                                      ,
 searchTermArg 
                                                                                                      ,
ApplicationConstants.DriverRole
                                                                                                       ,
startRowOfInterest
                                                                                                        ,
displayedRowsQuantity
                                                                                                     ,
sortColumn
                                                                                                      ,
isAscending);


            IEnumerable<Users> usersOfInterestList =         bv3.AsBsonArray.AsQueryable();
```

Is it better to start using C# invocation of stored javaScript in MongoDB as opposed to used MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714 API Query API?

Comment: Except... if you have authentication turned on, you have to have a role with "AnyAction on AnyResource" permission assigned to your user in order to execute "eval". This is a huge security risk as the default db user for your app would have global access to all functions on all databases and resources. see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#access-control

Comment: Update: Apparently "eval" is being dropped in a future version - although replacement functions are not yet available. see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17453